# Implement Dask workers on Kubernetes overriding default values

Tags: kubernetes, dask, dask-distributed

I'm trying to deploy Dask distributed on Kubernetes using Helm. It works fine, but I need to customize the deployment as described [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/kubernetes-helm.html#configure-environment). What I need is to have the workers access a mounted volume to read/write files. All the workers would have access to the same volume.

The example says that the values below would be used in values.yaml, so if the template doesn't have the volume-related variables there's no way I could make this work. Any ideas how to implement this, and if it's not possible?

This is the values.yaml that does not work:

```
worker:
  replicas: 3
  volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/mount/path"
      name: mypd
  env:
    - name: EXTRA_CONDA_PACKAGES
      value: numba xarray -c conda-forge
    - name: EXTRA_PIP_PACKAGES
      value: s3fs dask-ml --upgrade

jupyter:
  enabled: false
  
volumes:
  - name: mypd
    persistentVolumeClaim:
     claimName: myclaim-2
```

Comment: In a Helm chart, you can only customize things provided by the chart author; if the chart itself doesn't have a way to attach a volume to a pod then it's mostly not possible without modifying the chart.  But, it's also often difficult to get a ReadWriteMany volume.  Could you use some other kind of storage, like a database?

Comment: I found the template and allowed values, there's a `mount:` variable that I'm using. The main reason I need a volume is that I need to store somewhere the code of the Dask workers.

Comment: Typically you'd distribute code in Docker images, not volumes.  It's straightforward to update the `image:` in a Deployment to point to a newer tag (or, if needed, an older one) and Kubernetes will know how to restart everything to be consistent.  Getting access to a volume and managing the container lifecycle manually seems much harder.

Comment: I mostly work in a development environment, isn't it easier to copy a source file to a volume than  to recreate an image?

Comment: On Kubernetes?  Getting out-of-cluster access to volumes and managing process lifecycles is hard, and adding a volume mount actually adds a huge amount of content to the YAML files.  You'll probably want a CI system in any case and all but need a private registry, and redeploying a new image is better practice.  (Kubernetes is not really designed to be a development environment.)

Comment: I'm migrating from docker compose to Kubernetes. I currently develop and deploy on a volume that contains the code. Since I will deploy in Kubernetes, what is the best practice with regard to development environment? Should I continue developing in  docker compose and later deploy in Kubernetes the image containing the code?

Comment: As suggested above, k8s indeed was not designed as a development environment. You typically deploy an image on kubernetes when it becomes production-ready. You can take a look to a tool like skaffold which is shortly introduced in [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/kubernetes-local-development-the-correct-way-1bc4b11570d8)

Comment: I ended up developing with docker compose and deploying on Kubernetes, I will take a look at skaffold at some point in the future. The code in docker and Kubernetes is in a volume, not an image, for me it's easier to manage